# Powershell script for getting AD Group Membership for usernames

Tags: powershell

I want to write script for getting AD Group Membership that is beginning with SSL_VPN for usernames listed in a CSV.

I have tried so far :

```
Import-Csv C:\Users.csv |
  ForEach-Object -pv user { Get-AdUser -filter "displayname -eq '$($_.username)'"} |
    Get-ADprincipalGroupMembership |
      Select-Object @{ n = 'samaccountname'; e = { $user.samaccountname } }, name |
        Export-csv -path C:\UserPermiss.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Does `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Where Name -like 'SSL_VPN*'` do what you need? It is hard to tell if your issues are filtering for the groups or outputting in the proper format in the CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting users by their DisplayName property is not the safest thing to do. It would be so much better if your CSV file has other, more unique properties to go by, like `SamAccountName`, `UserPrincipalName`, `DistinguishedName` or `EmailAddress`..

Anyway, in your loop, you should check if a user with that name can be found and only if so, get the group membership.

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | ForEach-Object { 
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.username)'" -Properties DisplayName
    if ($user) {
        Get-ADprincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.DistinguishedName |
        Where-Object { $_.name -like 'SSL_VPN*' } |
        Select-Object @{ Name = 'SamAccountName'; Expression = { $user.SamAccountName } },
                      @{ Name = 'Group'; Expression = { $_.name }}
    } 
    else {
        Write-Warning "User '$($_.username)' not found"

        # if you want this message to also appear in your output CSV, do something like this:
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'SamAccountName' = "User '$($_.username)' not found"
            'Group' = ''
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\UserPermiss.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

If you want to see a warning message when the user is not a member of the SSL_VPN group, you can do:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | ForEach-Object { 
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.username)'" -Properties DisplayName
    if ($user) {
        $group = Get-ADprincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.DistinguishedName | 
                 Where-Object { $_.name -like 'SSL_VPN*' }
        if ($group) {
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                'SamAccountName' = $user.SamAccountName 
                'Group'          = $group.name
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "User '$($_.username)' is not a member of ssl_vpn group"
        }
    } 
    else {
        Write-Warning "User '$($_.username)' not found"
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\UserPermiss.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: how can I add `username is not member ssl_vpn group` warning

Comment: @Arbelac Please see my edit. If the user DisplayName could not be found, the code now emits the warning message as object to the output aswell. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Arbelac I also added code for displaying a warning when the user is not a member of the group

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this(frist line of csv must be samaccountname):

```
$users=Import-Csv D:\adusers.CSV
foreach($user in $users){
$groupname=Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.samaccountname |where {$_.name -like "SSL_VPN*"}|select -ExpandProperty name
    if($groupname -ne $null){
        foreach($group in $groupname){
        [string]$data=($user|select -ExpandProperty samaccountname)+';'+$group
        $data|Out-File -FilePath d:\stack.csv -Encoding utf8 -Append
        } 
    }
}
```